# Indexer explicit implemented IFormattable

Tags: c#, interface, indexer

I wrote myself an indexer, it works but as soon as I implement "IFormatable" explicit, it does not work anymore.

Why is does it not work and how to use it explicit ?

This is what I tried:

```
/// <summary>
/// Example of Coordinates for 3 dimensions.
/// </summary>
public class Coordinates:IFormattable
{
    #region Constructor
    public Coordinates(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
        _length = 3;
    }
    #endregion
    #region IFormattable implemented
    /// <summary>
    /// Formating custom string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="format">Format("A"-all value,...,"H"-)</param>
    /// <param name="formatProvider">Different culture</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string IFormattable.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (format==null)
        {
            return ToString(); //Fallbasck
        }
        else
        {
            switch (format.ToUpper())//gross, kleinschreibung egal
            {
                case "A": return ToString();
                case "X": return _x.ToString();
                case "Y": return _y.ToString();
                case "Z": return _z.ToString();
                case "H": return String.Format("{0:h}", ToString());
                default:
                    throw new FormatException(String.Format("Format {0} is not defined.", format));
            }
        }
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, null); //Error occurs here
    }

    #endregion
    #region overWriteToString
    /// <summary>
    /// will be called implicit
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>[x,y,z]</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[{0},{1},{2}]",_x,_y,_z);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    private int _x;

    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; }
    }

    private int _y;

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { _y = value; }
    }

    private int _z;

    public int Z
    {
        get { return _z; }
        set { _z = value; }
    }

    private int _length;

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Indexer
    /// <summary>
    /// My own indexer for x,y,z
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int this[int val]
    {
        get
        {

            switch (val)
            {
                case 0: return _x; ;
                case 1: return _y; ;
                case 2: return _z; ;
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Indexer not avaiable.");
            }

        }
        //kann auch setter haben
    }

    #endregion

}
```

I am learning C# in detail.

The error occurs here:

```
public string ToString(string format)
{
    return ToString(format, null); //Error occurs here
}
```

Comment: I know its been some time, but if you use properties with backing fields just for  
`public int Z
    {
        get { return _z; }
        set { _z = value; }
    }`
returning values, use autoproperties like `public int Z {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1):

By implementing `ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)` explicitly, you can only call it via a reference with a compile-time type of `IFormattable`.

You can do that by using `this`:

```
return ((IFormattable)this).ToString(format, null);
```

Or:

```
IFormattable formattable = this;
return formattable.ToString(format, null);
```

I'd probably add a comment to the code explaining *why* you're casting though, as it's not obvious until you notice that the method implements `IFormattable.ToString` explicitly.

Is there any reason you *want* to implement it explicitly, btw? It feels like something which should be accessible - and you *should* use the `IFormatProvider` passed in.

Comment: I made it explicity only, that I can see from where the "ToString(...)" comes, I know actually explicity implemention is invented if you have different interface which have the same method, but I could not think of a differen approach to made it clear, from where the "ToString(...)" comes

Comment: @user254197: What do you mean by "where ToString comes"?

Comment: I have 3 "ToString()"-methods and I would like to see that the one come from the interface "IFormattable.ToString(...)", to made it clear to everybody which of them(toString()) are mine and which of them are .Net based.

Comment: @user254197: Why would anyone care? You can *document* which one implements the interface, but using explicit interface implementation just makes it harder to use elsewhere...

Comment: You are right, i though if I do it like before you can see it at the first glance...